# How to run a custom npm script in an typescript app

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, next.js

I am using react-typescript in next.js app.
I want to run a npm script that will log out all `console.log()` present in home page `(_app.tsx)`

```
   //_app.tsx
   ...
   ...
   var num = 2
   console.log('log this out',num)
```

I have tried the following commands to check if it works in first place
(found this as a way to run typescript files by node)
1)`ts-node _app.tsx`
2)`tsc helloWorld.ts && node helloWorld.js`
3)`node _app.tsx`
None of them seem to work out

Comment: What happens when you run `ts-node _app.tsx`? That should work. No errors?

Comment: Next.js app is supposed to run with its environment, it obviously won't work if you run it with bare Node.

Comment: @EstusFlask So how I run It properly.

Comment: The way Next apps are supposed to run. Check https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started for starters.